# Is the behavior allowed for a feature in CSS Level 3 a *subset* of that allowed in CSS Level 2?

Tags: css

The CSS Working Group's "[Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) Snapshot 2010](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/)" says:

> Each level of CSS builds on the previous, refining definitions and
>   adding features. The feature set of each higher level is a superset of
>   any lower level, and ***the behavior allowed for a given feature in a
>   higher level is a subset of that allowed in the lower levels***. A user
>   agent conforming to a higher level of CSS is thus also conformant to
>   all lower levels.

I do not understand the sentence that I've emphasized in bold. Shouldn't it say that the behavior for a feature in a higher level is a *superset* of that allowed in in a lower level?

Can anyone provide an example to clarify it?

Comment: a new rule should be an extension, (improvement somehow) of an earlier one and nothing like an opposite. t' seems logical :)

Comment: No, it means subset. It's to allow the definitions of behaviour for each feature to be tightened in level 3 to resolve ambiguities. A browser therefore that complies with level 3 requirements will automatically comply with the looser level 2 requirements. But I don't know of a specific example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS Snapshot 2010 is as a whole vague and partly outdated. In the statement quoted, both “feature” and “behavior” are loose words, not well-defined terms, so the statement does not have an exact meaning. It seems probable that the meant “superset”, not “subset”. In any case, what the text says is partly incorrect: there are changes and omissions between “levels”. The “level” concept isn’t exact, far from that; there is no authoritative list of specifications and drafts that belong to “level 3”

Comment: By "omissions" between levels, you mean, for example, the [system-color keywords deprecated in CSS Color Module Level 3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#system-colors)?

Comment: @Xavi, that example is about deprecation, not removal. But, for example, CSS 2 has several properties that have aural effect, from `azimuth` to `volume`. They have been dropped.

Comment: I see that the [`azimuth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/azimuth) property applies to the 'aural' media type, which is actually *deprecated* too, not "dropped": "[The properties in this appendix apply to a media type 'aural', that was introduced in CSS2. The type 'aural' is now deprecated.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/aural.html#aural-media-group)". Anyway, I see your point that the statement I was trying to fully understand doesn't have a precise meaning.

Comment: Aural style sheet properties were part of CSS 2.0, defined but deprecated in CSS 2.1, and completely absent from anything called “CSS3”. Work has been done on “CSS Speech Module” (now a Candidate Recommendation), which has a very different set of properties.